# what are the more pythonic ways to limit a dict to elements that have a value?

Tags: python

given a dict of items

```
sample = { 'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3 , 'd':None , 'e':None }
```

i'd like to create a new dict that only has the items with a value.

this works..

```
a = dict([ i for i in testing.iteritems() if i[1]])
```

but i'm wondering if there's something more pythonic/readable.

i was hoping i could do something like

```
a = dict([ i for i in testing.____() if i.value() ])
```

but there's no standard iterator that works like that.

i'm just curious on this for readability purposes.

Comment: Your solution will also remove items with a value of 0 (zero), not just `None`. You might want `i[1] is None` instead.

Comment: good catch!  i totally want None. this is for handling API results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tuple unpacking (assigning each key and value to a separate variable, `k` and `v` in the following examples) and a dict comprehension:

```
a = {k: v for k, v in sample.iteritems() if v}
```

or test explicitly for `None` instead of all falsey values (numeric 0, empty sequences, etc.):

```
a = {k: v for k, v in sample.iteritems() if v is not None}
```

In Python 3, you need to use just `items()`:

```
a = {k: v for k, v in sample.items() if v}
```

For your sample, all above variations result in:

```
>>> sample = { 'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3 , 'd':None , 'e':None }
>>> {k: v for k, v in sample.iteritems() if v}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dict comprehension`: -

```
>>> {key: value for key, value in sample.iteritems() if value}
0: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

note: if using python 3 then simply use sample.items() as this is where 2.7 and 3 differ.

Comment: in all my years of Python, i never knew about dict comprehension.  this is blowing my mind.  i should have expected it - given list comprehensions.  but wow.  this is like having cake and eating cake and eating more cake.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
sample =  {'a': 1, 'e': 0, 'd': None}
k = {k: v for k, v in sample.items() if v is not None}

>>> k
{'a': 1, 'e': 0}
```